# Accessing my Google Drive API from my App

Tags: android, api, google-drive-android-api, drive

I would like to create a Google Android App and I want my app (ONLY my app and NO ONE ELSE) to have access to my Google Drive API. Right now, I published it as public and allowing anonymous connection to access it. Obviously this is very bad. I do not want to make user to Authencate with their account just so my app can access my google drive api. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding your question. Google Drive API requires authentication through OAUTH. Only people with your google credentials will be able to login to your account. For example if I used your application and logged in with my google account it would have access to my drive not yours.

Comment: I know. That's why I ask this question. Let me put it this way, I'm making an ebay kinda app. The Google api will allow me to get data from my drive, because of this I don't have to rent a host or build a hosting server. But I only want my app to access it though. No one else should have access to my api. OAuth will not work.